# Revert a merged pull request on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've created a pull request and I've merged it to an wrong branch. How can I revert it?

As far I've been to figuring out taking a look over there, I'm able to hard reset the destination branch... but, how about the pull request in `origin` repository?

I'm using Bitbucket and I've created the pull request from SourceTree (opening the Bitbucket page).

I've three branches I'm working on: `master`, `dev` and `create-alias`. `create-alias` was set up from `dev` and `dev` from `master`: `master -> dev -> create-alias`. The problem is I made a pull request from `create-alias` and I did merge it into `master` instead of `dev`.

I'm working on `create-alias` branch right now. The last commit on `create-alias` is `6ee20f9` and the merged commit on `master` is `be36f72`.

Could you write me down a bit about who to step-by-step revert it?

As far I've been able to figure out:

1. checkout on `master`.
2. revert -m 1 `6ee20f9`.
3. push.
4. checkout on `create-alias` and going on working.

Isn't it?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "Revert Pull Request" feature on Bitbucket as of this writing, but a [feature request exists for it](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/10228/revert-pull-request-button-bb-11090).

**Note**: Before you proceed, make sure your working copy is clean, with no uncommitted or unpushed changes.

So, you'll have to revert the merge in Git. First, find the SHA hash of the merge commit.

On the command line, this is:

```
git checkout <branch>
git pull
git log
```

Then, we revert the merge commit and push it:

```
git revert -m 1 <SHA-1>
git push
```

In SourceTree, first checkout the branch in question, then **Pull**. Find the merge commit in the log window, then right click it, and click **Copy SHA-1 to Clipboard...**. Then go to **Actions --> Open in Terminal**. Once the terminal opens, type:

```
git revert -m 1 <SHA-1 (from clipboard)>
git push
```

Unfortunately, SourceTree doesn't have a way to simply right-click and revert a merge, but a [feature request exists for it](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1832).

Comment: Useful and good to know.

Answer (score 43):

Bitbucket has a "revert" button on Pull Requests now.

[image]

Note it doesn't automatically update the branch the original PR was merged into it.  It creates a new branch with a commit that reverts the PR:

[image]

You then can create a PR from this branch and merge it.

Comment: I don't see this in our Bitbucket. We're running Atlassian Bitbucket v5.15.0.  Enterprise edition, or something like that.

Comment: @DavidHempy It might only be available on the cloud version, I can see it there. Note if you're using the "new" PR view you'll have to switch back to the old version to see this button

Comment: I would really want this button right now, but our local bitbucket doesn't have it yet :(

Comment: This is nice but what to do if you merge feature-branch into master, revert master then merge same feature-branch into develop and want to merge into master later. Because those commits are in the history they will just be super-ceded by the reversion when trying to merge. Is there an alternate strategy?

Answer (score 10):

Bitbucket now has the ['Revert Merged Pull Request' feature](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2017/07/27/4-features-in-4-weeks-heres-whats-new-in-bitbucket-cloud/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=bitbucket_product-digest-six&utm_content=VC&jobid=102592242&subid=1290827960) released.

Comment: Didn’t you mean “now has the Revert Merged Pull Request”?

Answer (score 4):

With bitbucket, we can't revert a merged pull request. The revert option which is present in the pull request will create a new branch with a new head(before this commit). That branch later you have to merge into your master/release branch. This is all as communicated by the official [Bitbucket doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/merge-a-pull-request/#Revert-a-merged-pull-request).
[image]